# Google Analytics domain data without filtering

Tags: api, dns, google-analytics

I run a web service with many sub-sites. Example URLs of sub sites:

domain.com/sub/jim
domain.com/sub/jon
domain.com/sub/dave

etc (around 3,000 currently and growing).

We currently offer basic stats reporting (page views and unique pageviews) that we can get from Google analytics (we currently process a XML file of the /sub/ drilldown for this info).

This all works well.

What I'd like to do is offer domain mapping through a CNAME record. Example:

```
www.jim.com    acts as    domain.com/sub/jim
```

Usually I'd setup a filter in GA for this new domain, but obviously I don't want to set up 3,000 filters.

Clearly with the new domain "jim" won't be a drilldown of "/sub/" anymore, so how can I access this data through Googles API or emailed reports?