# Basic site analytics doesn't tally with Google data

Tags: google-analytics, keyword, metrics, pageviews

After being stumped by an earlier quesiton: [SO google-analytics-domain-data-without-filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343323/google-analytics-domain-data-without-filtering)

I've been experimenting with a very basic analytics system of my own.

MySQL table:

```
hit_id, subsite_id, timestamp, ip, url
```

The subsite_id let's me drill down to a folder (as explained in the previous question).

I can now get the following metrics:

- Page Views - Grouped by subsite_id and date
- Unique Page Views - Grouped by subsite_id, date, url, IP (not nesecarily how Google does it!)
- The usual "most visited page", "likely time to visit" etc etc.

I've now compared my data to that in Google Analytics and found that **Google has lower values each metric**. Ie, my own setup is counting more hits than Google.

So I've started discounting IP's from various web crawlers, Google, Yahoo & Dotbot so far.

Short Questions:

1. Is it worth me collating a list of
   all major crawlers to discount, is
   any list likely to change regularly?
2. Are there any other obvious filters
   that Google will be applying to GA
   data?
3. What other data would you
   collect that might be of use further
   down the line?
4. What variables does
   Google use to work out entrance
   search keywords to a site?

The data is only going to used internally for our own "subsite ranking system", but I would like to show my users some basic data (page views, most popular pages etc) for their reference.

Comment: I've found that Google analytics takes sometimes 6 hours or more to report stuff (this was a couple years ago, maybe its faster now?).  Could this explain your discrepancy?  Plus I don't think they display things in my time zone.

Comment: Hi mlsteeves, yes there is a delay but I've deliberately used data from last week instead. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: what is the source of your data?  Your server logs?

Comment: Hi doug, I'm actually logging this using PHP on each page load into a MySQL table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under-reporting by the client-side rig versus server-side eems to be the usual outcome of these comparisons.

Here's how i've tried to reconcile the disparity when i've come across these studies:

*Data Sources recorded in server-side collection but not client-side:*

- hits from 
     **mobile devices** that don't support javascript (this is probably a
     significant source of disparity
     between the two collection
     techniques--e.g., Jan 07 [comScore
     study](http://www.comscore.com/press/release.asp?press=1432) showed that 19% of UK
     Internet Users access the Internet
     from a mobile device)
- hits from **spiders**, bots (which you
  mentioned already)

*Data Sources/Events that server-side collection tends to record with greater fidelity (much less false negatives) compared with javascript page tags:*

- hits from users behind **firewalls**,
  particularly corporate
  firewalls--firewalls block page tag,
  plus some are configured to
  reject/delete cookies.
- hits from users who have **disabled
  javascript in their browsers**--five
  percent, according to the [W3C
  Data](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp)
- hits from users who **exit the page
  before it loads**. Again, this is a
  larger source of disparity than you
  might think. The most
  frequently-cited [study](http://www.stonetemple.com/article/analytics-report-august-2007-part2.shtml) to
  support this was conducted by Stone
  Temple Consulting, which showed that
  the difference in unique visitor
  traffic between two identical sites
  configured with the same web
  analytics system, but which differed
  only in that the js tracking code was
  placed at the **bottom** of the pages
  in one site, and at the **top** of
  the pages in the other--was **4.3**%

---

FWIW, here's the scheme i use to remove/identify spiders, bots, etc.:

1. monitor requests for our
   **robots.txt** file: then of course filter all other requests from same
   IP address + user agent (not all
   spiders will request robots.txt of
   course, but with miniscule error,
   any request for this resource is
   probably a bot.
2. compare user agent and ip addresses
   against published lists: **iab.net** and
   **user-agents.org** publish the two
   lists that seem to be the most
   widely used for this purpose
3. **pattern analysis**: nothing sophisticated here;
   we look at (i) page views as a
   function of time (i.e., clicking a
   lot of links with 200 msec on each
   page is probative); (ii) the path by
   which the 'user' traverses out Site,
   is it systematic and complete or
   nearly so (like following a
   back-tracking algorithm); and (iii)
   precisely-timed visits (e.g., 3 am
   each day).

Answer (score 1):

Lots of people block Google Analytics for privacy reasons.

Comment: Interesting! I doubt this is a large proportion of our traffic though. It's definitely not a technical community.

Comment: It takes about 2 seconds to install AdBlock in Firefox, technical community not required. This blocks Google Analytics by default.

Comment: Most of my users haven't heard of Firefox, have no idea what "installing" something is and certainly wouldn't have a clue what AdBlock would do or how to get it. It's 90% Internet explorer straight out of the box.

But I take your point :)

Answer (score 0):

Biggest reasons are users have to have JavaScript enabled and load the entire page as the code is often in the footer. Awstars, other serverside solutions like yours will get everything. Plus, analytics does a real good job identifying bots and scrapers.